# Search for a specific file in S3 using boto

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I am using boto to parse S3 buckets. Basically I want to file a certain file in the bucket (say *.header or any other regex expression that has been provided by user). Since I could not find any function for that in boto I was trying to write a BFS routine to search through content of each folder but I couldn’t find any method to get contents of folder by key/key.name (which I am getting by bucketObj.list() ). Is there any other method for doing this?

For instance, lets say i have multiple folders in bucket 
like

```
mybucket/A/B/C/x.txt
mybucket/A/B/D/y.jpg
mybucket/A/E/F/z.txt
```

and i want to find where are *.txt

so the boto script should return me following result

```
mybucket/A/B/C/x.txt
mybucket/A/E/F/z.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do wildcard searches or file-globbing service-side with S3.  The only filtering available via the API is a `prefix`.  If you specify a `prefix` string, only results that begin with that `prefix` will be returned.

Otherwise, all filtering would have to happen on the client-side.  Or, you could store your keys in a database and use that to do the searching and only retrieve the matches from S3.